# decimal to binary conversion of a number which is having fractional part too

Tags: math, binary, numbers, decimal, data-conversion

How to represent 500.2 in binary number system. I want to know the conversion method. I know how to convert numbers without points but if point comes in any number I don't know how to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the conversion description from [Modern Digital Electronics 4E](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Modern_Digital_Electronics_4e.html?id=ts7JE_D4RLEC&hl=en)

**Decimal to Binary conversion :**

> Any decimal number can be converted into its equivalent binary number.
>   ***For integers***, *the conversion is obtained by continuous division by 2
>   and keeping track of the remainder*s, while ***for fractional parts***, *the
>   conversion is affected by continuous multiplication by 2 and keeping
>   track of the integers generated*.

The conversion process in your case is illustrated below :-

```
500/2 = 250 Remainder = 0
250/2 = 125 Reaminder = 0
125/2 = 62  Remainder = 1
62/2  = 31  Remainder = 0
31/2  = 15  Remainder = 1
15/2  =  7  Remainder = 1
7/2   =  3  Remainder = 1
3/2   =  1  Remainder = 1
1/2   =  0  Remainder = 1
```

So, the order of evaluation is that topmost remainder will go to LSB, the bottom-most remainder would go to MSB.

Therefore, (500)<sub>2</sub> = 111110100.

Now, talking about the fractional part, we would go as follows :-

```
// separate the integer generated(0 or 1) on the left hand side of the fraction/dot,
// and ensure only fractional part between 0 and 1 are allowed in the next step
0.2 * 2 = 0.4 ,  so, keep 0 in the bag
0.4 * 2 = 0.8 ,  so, keep 0 in the bag
0.8 * 2 = 1.6 ,  so, keep 1 in the bag, and next put 0.6 to the next step
0.6 * 2 = 1.2,   so, keep 1 in the bag, and next put 0.2 to the next step
0.2 * 2 = 0.4,   so, keep 0 in the bag...
// and so on as we see that it would continue(repeating) the same pattern.
```

As we find that the series would go on infinitely, we can consider only the precision upto certain decimal places.

So, if I assume that the required precision is 4 digits after the dot, then the answer would be the sequence in which the digits are being placed in the bag, i.e.,

(0.2)<sub>2</sub> = 0.00110011...
                     = 0.0011....
                     = 0.0011.

Now, combinedly, (500.2)<sub>2</sub> = 111110100.0011 .

Comment: Wow, this is a great answer. Now I have to retract my CV on the question. :/

Comment: @BhargavRao - Thanks, but, I really don't know whether such an easy question's answer deserves appreciation OR not! Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: Questions may be easy, but it is the effort shown in the answer that is more important. The effort gets an upvote. Do edit the question and the title to make it more visible to the "Google" audience. Cheers and All the best.

Comment: @BhargavRao - Thanks, already did that. And, I appreciate your appreciation of the answer, :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good webpage about it. I don't know if it answers your question :
http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

### Edit

from that link

[image]

**Usage**: You can either convert a number by choosing its binary representation in the button-bar, the other fields will be updated immediately. Or you can enter a binary number, a hexnumber or the decimal representation into the corresponding textfield and press return to update the other fields. To make it easier to spot eventual rounding errors, the selected float number is displayed after conversion to double precision.

**Special Values**: You can enter the words "Infinity", "-Infinity" or "NaN" to get the corresponding special values for IEEE-754. Please note there are two kinds of zero: +0 and -0.

**Conversion**: The value of a IEEE-754 number is computed as:
sign * 2exponent * mantissa
The sign is stored in bit 32. The exponent can be computed from bits 24-31 by subtracting 127. The mantissa (also known as significand or fraction) is stored in bits 1-23. An invisible leading bit (i.e. it is not actually stored) with value 1.0 is placed in front, then bit 23 has a value of 1/2, bit 22 has value 1/4 etc. As a result, the mantissa has a value between 1.0 and 2. If the exponent reaches -127 (binary 00000000), the leading 1 is no longer used to enable gradual underflow.

**Underflow**: If the exponent has minimum value (all zero), special rules for denormalized values are followed. The exponent value is set to 2-126 while the "invisible" leading bit for the mantissa is no longer used. The range of the mantissa is now [0:1).

**Note**: The converter used to show denormalized exponents as 2-127 and a denormalized mantissa range [0:2). This is effectively identical to the values above, with a factor of two shifted between exponent and mantissa. However this confused people and was therefore changed (2015-09-26).

**Rounding errors**: Not every decimal number can be expressed exactly as a floating point number. This can be seen when entering "0.1" and examining its binary representation which is either slightly smaller or larger, depending on the last bit.

**Other representations:** The hex representation is just the integer value of the bitstring printed as hex. Don't confuse this with true hexadecimal floating point values in the style of 0xab.12ef.

Comment: It doesn't answer OP's question. OP is asking for manual decimal to binary conversion!

Comment: Thank you for your **excellent** answer, as to how to represent 500.2 in binary. That was the question afterall.

Comment: @Drew I dunno if you were sarcastic. But this answer provides a borderline help to the OP. Note the statement *I want to know the conversion method*. 500.2 was just an example.  Whatever be it, the question is too broad. This answer would be the best if it was a comment.

Comment: @BhargavRao well here is a paste I made in another room concerning this: "he asked how to represent it. The guy showed him how to represent it. The question has no language tags. To me, the question is already answered"

Comment: @Drew The OP clearly has mentioned that he needs the method. Anyway it is a VLQ answer also. The OP has not explained anything about the link. (If the link dies - the answer dies). But let's end this convo here. I do understand your thoughts. Cheers and Best of luck.